# Rank objects based on multiple fields

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a scenario in which I want to sort and rank the list of records based on different properties. Each object has a **Total property** and also a list of integer value called **Scores**,
The Model is like

```
public class Routine
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int Total { get; set; }

    public List<int> Scores { get; set; }
}
```

I want to rank the records,

- First: Based on the **Total Property**
- Second: Based on the first value in the **Scores** property
- Then: Based on the second value in the **Scores** property
- And so on

For example I consider these three records.

[image]

Thanks for any help and ideas.

Comment: No,  for me the ThenBy needs to sort based on multiple values, Scores property

Comment: You can add `ThenBy`-clauses as many as needed.

Comment: can you also provide code of your model in case given answers aren't what you need?

Comment: I edit my question and add the model as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using linq you can use Orderby(Descending) followed by chaining any number of ThenBy(Descending) clauses together.

```
        var soterdList= initialList.OrderByDescending(r => r.Total)
            .ThenByDescending(r => r.Scores.FirstOrDefault())
            .ThenByDescending(r => r.Scores.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Comment: Since the second property is a list of integer the ThenBy seems doesn't work for me

Comment: @ali I've updated the code to suit your model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`.

```
var ordered = items.OrderBy(x => x.TotalProperty).ThenBy(x => x.S1).ThenBy(x => x.S2);
```

You can also use `OrderByDescending` if you want descending order.

Comment: Since the second property is a list of integer the ThenBy seems doesn't work for me

Comment: What do you mean a list of integers? In the question you have 1 integer per row. Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: The second property is Scores which is List<int>, I edit the question and add my model as well